# how to encrypt & decrypt NSdata in plist iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm saving a name & 3 phone numbers into plist. I need to encrypt data when I hit the save button. 
Which one is more convenient RNCryptor or NSData + AES. How do I use it ?

```
 -(void)saveButton
    {    

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
        self.personName = theName.text;
        self.phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3]; [phoneNumbers addObject:homePhone.text];
        [phoneNumbers addObject:workPhone.text];
        [phoneNumbers addObject:cellPhone.text];
        NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: personName, phoneNumbers, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Phones", nil]];
        NSString *error = nil;
        NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization
                             dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
        if(plistData) {
            // write plistData to our Data.plist file
            [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there some reason you would not just write it to the Keychain?

Comment: In future I might want to encrypt Image & save it into plist so started saving & retrieving data in plist. I'm new to iOS and have no idea about keychain. A little guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of NSData + AES implementations and a lot of those are severely flawed. Additionally many do not handle key extension for strings and random ivs.

If you want security go with RNCryptor, it is being actively implemented and provided good security.

Now the next question: How will you secure the key? Do research the Keychain, there is no more secure way to save the encryption key.

But make sure you need to do this, look at the `NSData` security options: `NSDataWritingOptions`.

Comment: I am using this code to encrypt but how do I check whether the data has been encrypted or not ? Is it correct way to encrypt ?

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"data.plist"]];
NSError *error1;
NSData *bac = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"abcdef" error:&error1];
NSString *pathToDesktop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/rajparmar/Desktop/rajuencrypt.text"];
[bac writeToFile:pathToDesktop atomically:YES];

Comment: The there is no error and the output of encryption when the NSData is NSLog'ed looks like complete gibberish it is encrypted. ;-) Encrypted data looks like random bytes. I can't help with RNCryptor, I don't use it but have examined it and it is a best-in-class encryption. One thing, always choose the method that has an error return, in this case in-place of `writeToFile:atomically:` choose: `writeToFile:options:error:`.